# Mysql syntax Limit by an integer row

Tags: php, mysql

i want to write a MySql function that the Limit is set by a row on the table called.

Let me explain.

```
$query=mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT a_row, b_row, c_row FROM table WHERE a_row='something' ORDER BY 'whatever' **LIMIT 'c_row'** DESC")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

c_row in an integer number on the db.
I tried to make a variable before calling the $query from the row (c_row) but i dont think thats possible.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: i want to do it because the row contains the number that i want to return something

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to access the value of `c_row` and use it for the `LIMIT` clause.

```
$query=mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT a_row, b_row, c_row FROM table
WHERE a_row='something' ORDER BY 'whatever' LIMIT (SELECT c_row from table) DESC")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay but i am getting this error. Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT times from advertisments) DESC' . times is the row i want to call and advertisments is the table.